# JUnit Test Case not appearing in JUnit Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

I have two test cases in two separate classes. Only the first one appears in the JUnit explorer.

The first test case I added appears in the JUnit explorer and the second test case does not. When I run tests through the JUnit Explorer it runs the first test and not the second.

Here is the Package Explorer for the project:
[image]

Here is the JUnit Explorer:
[image]

Here is the Test Case that appears in the JUnit Explorer:
[image]

Here is the Test Case that does not appear in the JUnit Explorer:
[image]

Comment: That's not a JUnit _explorer_, but some kind of JUnit _results_ view. So, only the tests that have been executed are displayed. Right-click the `src` folder and choose _Run As > JUnit Test_ for all tests in the _JUnit_ view.

Comment: @howlger Bingo! Add an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a JUnit *explorer*, but some kind of **JUnit *results* view**, only the tests that have been executed are displayed.

**Right-click** the **`src`** folder and choose ***Run As > JUnit Test*** to execute all tests and to get the results in the JUnit view.